# Getting map tiles for osmdroid without mobile atlas creator

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am writing a new android app that requires offline maps. I have been trying to use mobile atlas creator to get the map tiles, however mobile atlas creator has been marked by open street maps as a misuser of their services. You can be seen when trying to download a map using mobile atlas creator and getting blocked off tiles. I would like to know if there are any other options for generating map tiles for osmdroid for use on a android or if there are a better option for offline maps on a android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'Maperitive' (http://maperitive.net/)

It works in much the same way, but you'll have to package the generated map tiles into a .zip file manually to use them with osmdroid.

Answer (score 1):

Change the map source in mobile atlas creator to Mapquest. Download all you want, check the folder (unzipped) name and rename it to MapquestOSM if you're using osmdroid to render.